# How to stop implementation of start button onclick listener when click on stop button onclick listener. please go through code

Tags: java, android

> on click stop button. how to stop while loop in start button on click listener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    'final EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);
    final Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    final Button stop =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    start.setText("Start");
    stop.setText("Stop");
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                while(true){
                    try {
                               //some functionality.
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }

                }//while ends here
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //stop functionality

        }
    });
}
}
```

on click stop button.  how to stop while loop in start button on click listener

Answer (score 0):

Because of how you are writing breaking the execution of the while loop, it seems that your code is meant for threads, basically MainActivity would have a reference to a thread that it would be created on the on start click event, this thread reference needs to be saved in a variable MainActivity. The on stop click event would call the interrupt() method on the thread created. Remember to run the thread in the background so you don't block the UI thread and you can actually receive the click listener of the stop button.

For more information on background threads: [run threads on background](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html)
For more information on stopping threads: [thread interruption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            "final EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);"
            final Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
            final Button stop =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
            start.setText("Start");
            stop.setText("Stop");

            boolean b = true;

            start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    while(b){
                        try {
                            //some functionality.
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            break;
                        }

                    }//while ends here
                }
            });
            stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    b = false;

                }
            });
        }
    }
```